# Test dynamic link on iOS without publishing first to the app store

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

My flutter project is using firebase_dynamic_link package. I followed the instruction to register both my android and ios app on the firebase console without any problem. I've tested it out on android and it's working fine, opening the app I have running.

On iOS, I was expecting it to open the app I have running on it, instead I just get redirected to a preview page link.

Is it not opening my ios app because :

- It's not yet published on the app store ?
- Or is it because of an error in setup?

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it in Firebase Console when you create/edit the dynamic link.

[image: firebase console checkbox]